# I need a way for the user to select 4 boxes and arrange them in order

Tags: drag-n-drop, prioritization, reorder

In my example I was thinking as the user clicks on a box the checkmark will be selected and there will a border displayed. After selecting the 4 selections they can drag them in order from left to right?

Or maybe the select the checkbox and in the box there could be a dropdown with options 1-4 so they can reorder them as they choose.
[image]

Comment: can you rephrase your question? It's not clear what are you asking

Comment: @Devin Thanks Devin. I tried to reframe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple possible options here. You can either:

1. Select 4 items, then on a different page/section reorder them from 1-4.
2. Have the user select the items in the order they want, so the first item they select is #1, the second item is #2, and so on.

I would suggest #2, where the user selects the items and the items are arranged in the order they selected them this reduces the number of steps and redundancy in selecting the list items. If you must go with option 1, make sure that the "reorder" section is on a different page so the user doesn't see all the options they didn't pick while reordering.

Comment: Thanks Gene I like option 2 also. I am thinking if they change their mind and want to revise the order again since there only 4 options using a reset button would be the easiest option.